# How do I find the most recent event in sequence based on the timestamp of another event

Tags: sql, hive, hql, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I have a table of app event data. Each row has a user_id, a timestamp, a page_id, an event_name, and other fields. The events I care about right now are the page_open and button_click events, but there are 10 other event types that could happen in between, like scrolling. The user might open the same page multiple times, but only click a button on the page every so often, like you see in the example below.

```
user_id  timestamp   page_id  event_name
-------  ----------  -------  --------------
     71  12:00:34        307  page_open
     88  13:01:44        307  page_open
     71  13:02:09        307  page_open
     71  13:02:11        307  scroll
     71  13:04:41        307  page_open
     71  13:04:42        307  scroll
     71  13:04:45        307  button_click_a
     71  13:08:30        307  page_open
     88  13:09:01        307  button_click_b
```

For each page_open event for each user, I want an additional column that tells me if a button was eventually clicked. I don't have a page "session" to use, so I have to look for the max page_open timestamp that occurred before the button_click timestamp. Said another way, I want to transform the above table into the following table

```
user_id  timestamp   page_id  event_name  button_event
-------  ----------  -------  ----------  --------------
     71  12:00:34        307  page_open   NULL
     88  13:01:44        307  page_open   button_click_b
     71  13:02:09        307  page_open   NULL
     71  13:04:41        307  page_open   button_click_a
     71  13:08:30        307  page_open   NULL
```

I tried to separate the page_open and button_click events into two tables and do a `LEFT JOIN` on user_id and page_id like you see below, but of course that didn't work because it matched the button clicks to all page_opens with that page_id. I only want to match the button click to it's corresponding page_open event.

```
SELECT
    a.user_id,
    a.timestamp,
    a.page_id,
    a.event_name,
    b.event_name AS button_event
FROM
    (SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_name = 'page_open') a
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_name = 'button_click_a' OR event_name = 'button_click_b') b
ON
    a.user_id = b.user_id AND
    a.page_id = b.page_id
;
```

I'm new to working with event data like this. Any help you can provide would be awesome. What is the correct way to approach this problem?

Comment: Please tag the database you are using. (With version would be nice also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a gaps-and-islands problem. You need to define groups of adjacent records that start with a "page open" event; I would recommend a window count:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        max(case when event_name <> 'page_open' then event_name end) 
            over(partition by page_id, user_id, grp) button_event
    from (
        select 
            t.*,
            sum(case when event_name = 'page_open' then 1 else 0 end) 
                over(partition by page_id, user_id order by timestamp) grp
        from mytable t
        where event_name = 'page_open' or event_name like 'button_click_%'
    ) t
) t
where event_name = 'page_open'
```

You did not tell which database you are running. This uses standard window functions syntax, and should work in all databases that support window functions.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=408ada68b85a066dc67a331fc6c107c4)**:

```
user_id | timestamp | page_id | event_name | grp | button_event  
------: | :-------- | ------: | :--------- | --: | :-------------
     71 | 12:00:34  |     307 | page_open  |   1 | null          
     88 | 13:01:44  |     307 | page_open  |   1 | button_click_b
     71 | 13:02:09  |     307 | page_open  |   2 | null          
     71 | 13:04:41  |     307 | page_open  |   3 | button_click_a
     71 | 13:08:30  |     307 | page_open  |   4 | null
```

Comment: Just added a tag for Hive/HQL

Comment: @sbruce: Hive supports window functions, so this should work.

Comment: I like this answer because it helped me understand how to create a page_num, which I can also use to create a page_session_id. Thank you!

Comment: Why use max in the middle query?

Answer (score 0):

> look for the max page_open timestamp that occurred before the
> button_click timestamp.

Rephrasing to *look if the next row is a button-click*.
You didn't tag the DBMS, but most system support Lag/LEAD:

```
with cte as 
 (
   select
      user_id,
      timestamp,
      page_id,
      event_name,
      -- find the next non-'page_open' event
      lead(case when event_name <> 'page_open'
               then event_name
          end)
      over (partition by user_id
            order by timestamp) AS button_event
   from mytable
   where event_name in ('page_open','button_click_a','button_click_b')
 )
select *
from cte 
where event_name = 'page_open' -- remove click rows
```

See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=5f1962157dce04bd61dce3b842667a4a)

Comment: Just added a tag for Hive/HQL

Comment: I like this answer because it is condensed. Thank you!